# How to make values unique in cassandra

Tags: constraints, unique, cassandra-2.0

I want to make unique constraint in cassandra .
As i want to all the value in my column be unique in my column family
ex:
name-rahul
phone-123
address-abc

now i want that i this row no values equal to rahul ,123 and abc get inserted again on seraching on datastax i found that i can achieve it by doing query on partition key as IF NOT EXIST ,but not getting the solution for getting all the 3 values uniques 
means if 
name- jacob
phone-123
address-qwe

this should also be not inserted into my database as my phone column has the same value as i have shown with name-rahul.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that constraints of any type are not supported in Cassandra. They are simply too expensive as they must involve multiple nodes, thus defeating the purpose of having eventual consistency in first place. If you needed to make a single column unique, then there could be a solution, but not for more unique columns. For the same reason - there is no isolation, no consistency (C and I from the ACID). If you really need to use Cassandra with this type of enforcement, then you will need to create some kind of synchronization application layer which will intercept **all** requests to the database and make sure that the values are unique, and all constraints are enforced. But this won't have anything to do with Cassandra.

Comment: then can you tell me some alternate solution for making columns unique.

Comment: As I already mentioned, your application layer needs to make sure it enforces uniqueness before it inserts data to Cassandra. How you implement it - another question. But this is not something that Cassandra can enforce.

Comment: it means i would have to do some read operations ,but i was asking that is there any solution to get uniqueness  without doing reading operation.

Comment: Any solution will have to be built outside of Cassandra as by the nature, an eventually consistent database, won't be able to serve as a synchronization source. You will need to teach your applications how to communicate with each other directly to keep the values unique, totally excluding Cassandra out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and the existing answer is correct (you can't do constraints in C*), but you can solve the problem using batched creates. Create one or more additional tables, each with the constrained column as the primary key and then batch the creates, which is an atomic operation. If any of those column values already exist the entire batch will fail. For example if the table is named **Foo**, also create **Foo_by_Name** (primary key Name), **Foo_by_Phone** (primary key Phone), and **Foo_by_Address** (primary key Address) tables. Then when you want to add a row, create a batch with all 4 tables. You can either duplicate all of the columns in each table (handy if you want to fetch by Name, Phone, or Address), or you can have a single column of just the Name, Phone, or Address.