# How to have unique key except primary key in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, unique-key

I am not good in English! 
There is a table in Cassandra 3.5 which all columns of a row don't come at same time. Unique of table is some columns that are unique in a row together, but some of them are null at first. I can not set them the primary key because of null value. I have identify a column with name id and type `uuid` in Cassandra.

How can I have a unique key with that columns together in Cassandra? 
Is my data model true? 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. It's not a relational DB. Use clustering and/or partitioning keys to add an unique constraint.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28759358/919514)

To store unique values, create a separate table having your unique value as a key. Check if it exists by requesting this table before inserting a row. But beware, even doing this, you cannot ensure it will be unique in your final table if you have two concurrent inserts.

Basically, I would recommend using Cassandra as it really is: A data store. And find a way to implement your business logic where it belongs: in your code.